# Magento2.3: How do I call subtotal for creating condition for different stores in Cart?

Tags: cart, magento2.3, subtotal

How do I call the subtotal for different products in different stores in block .php or view .phtml files?

I set the price of the products manually for different stores.

I want to write a condition to show/not show something in the shopping cart page.

**Example:**

For subtotal greater than USD30, something will show in US store cart page.
For subtotal greater than HK$300, something will show in HongKong Store cart page.
For subtotal greater than EUR30, something will show in Europe store cart page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

Differentiate store by using store code and set different subtotal condition, as below

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeCode = $storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
?>

<?php if (($storeCode == 'en' && $subTotal >= 30) || ($storeCode == 'my' && $subTotal >= 60) || ($storeCode == 'hk' && $subTotal >= 300)): ?>
```